# Python ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (1,6) (1,2)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, array-broadcasting

I am trying to use numpy to generate a set of numbers for a neural network code, but I am encountering an error with the following line:

```py
import numpy as no
import pandas as pd
Bg_data = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/.kaggle/Bg_small_Dato.csv")
y = [0,0,0]
data = np.array(bg_data)
m, n = data.shape #shape is (11,2)
no.random.shuffle(data)
X_train = data_train[1:n]
X_train.shape #shape is (1,6)
Class Layer_Dense:
   def __init__(self,n_inputs, n_neurons)):
      self.weights = 0.1 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
      self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))
   def forward(self, inputs)
      self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases

...
dense1 = Layer_Dense(2,6)
activation1 = Activation_ReLU()
dense2 = Layer_Dense(6,2)
activation2 = Activation_Softmax()

...

...
loss_function = Loss_categoricalcrossentropy()
Lowest_loss = 9999999
...
...

for iteration in range(10000):
   dense1.weights += 0.05 * np.random.randn(1,6)
   dense1.biases += 0.05 * np.random.randn(1,6)
   dense2.weights += 0.05 * np.random.randn(6,2)
   dense2.biases = 0.05 * np.random.randn(1,6)

   dense1.forward(X_train)
```

This code works fine for other neural network codes, but it's not working in this case. I have edited the post to give more clarity about the challenge. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: full error message please

Comment: You don't show the code where the actual error occurs, but I'm guessing you need to do `np.random.randn(1,2)`.

Comment: `import numpy as np;dense2 = 0.05 * np.random.randn(1,6);print(dense2)` works fine for me

Comment: While full code is good, I didn't ask for that!  If you want help, you have to provide enough information.  We shouldn't have to guess where the problem occurs or what the variables are like.